# How to display GIF in app?

Tags: swift, animation, animated-gif

i am trying to load gif in my project as per my requirement to show animation,
 i have used third-party lib for showing gif animation, 
 i have copied same code from demo project but not working in my project.

**Here is my code :**

```
let animatedGif = UIImage.gif(name: "loading")
```

Comment: As a rule, GIF is not supported in iOS. As such, you probably need to use that "third party lib". With the code you posted, there's not enough details to either (a) identify your issue or (b) duplicate it.

Comment: using this third-party lib : https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif

Comment: you are using swiftgif lib and your code as per the demo, please verify where you place your gif image, your gif images must be placed in the bundle not in Images.xcassets, kindly check and verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Patrick suggested, you have to replace your image path from asset folder and move it in your app’s bundle. This issue is also raised in its official git library’s issue tab. https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif/issues/67.